# Caching forcedly stopped, cache adapter is obsolete error in Xodus Databse

Tags: xodus

I am using xodus database for my application and I have 3 simple entities in it. when the application receives bulk load the xodus throws Caching forcedly stopped, cache adapter is obsolete error. because of that the GC operation is not happening and the application crashes.

Error Message : [EntityStoreSharedAsyncProcessor0] INFO jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.EntityIterableCache - Caching forcedly stopped, cache adapter is obsolete: 7-0-0

when the load is minimum, this issue does not occur.

Any ideas for this issue?

Comment: This is not an error message, it's a message logged with the INFO level. What "GC operation" not happening do you mean? Why do you think your application crashes?

Comment: Usually the GarbageCollector is started with "Exodus shared background cleaner" thread and deletes the \db\00000002800.xd files after 3 files from the entity. But when the load is high like 100 calls per sec, the "Caching forcedly stopped" messages getting printed and the GC logs not printing. and after some time the application throws Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error.

Comment: Under load, background cleaner can wait for a lesser load, this is generally okay. The "Caching forcedly stopped" messages typically appear under high write load. this is not a problem itself as well. As for `OutOfMemoryError`, please drop a mail to xodus-feedback@jetbrains.com, we can try to help to configure your application.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a relation between "Caching" and background cleaner? Is there a way configure background cleaner to run on high load also?

Comment: Set `EnvironmentConfig.setMemoryUsagePercentage(40)`. If after that you still would experience `OutOfMemoryError`, then set `EnvironmentConfig.setMemoryUsagePercentage(30)`. If this won't help then there is a leak or a misconfiguration in your application.